# TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable error cycling through pages on a dynamic webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, typeerror

This is the [site](http://www.nigeriatradehub.gov.ng/Organizations) I want to scrape.

I want to scrape all the information in the table on the first page:

[image]

then click on the second and do the same:

[image]

And so on until the 51st page. I know how to use selenium to click on page two:

```
link = "http://www.nigeriatradehub.gov.ng/Organizations"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(link)
xpath = '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/a[1]'
find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

But I don't know how to set the code up so that it cycles through each page. The process of me getting the xpath is a manual one in the first place (I go on to Firefox, inspect the item and copy it into the code), so I don't know how to automate that step in and of itself and then the following ones.

I tried going a level higher in the webpage html and choosing the entire section of the page with the elements I want, and cycling through them, but that doesn't work because it's a Firefox web object(see below). Here'a a snapshot of the relevant part of the page source:

[image]

By calling the xpath of the higher class like so:

```
path = '//*[@id="dnn_ctr454_View_OrganizationsListViewDataPager"]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
```

and trying to see if I can cycle though it:

```
for i in driver.find_element_by_xpath(path):
    i.click()
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change ```driver.find_element_by_xpath``` to ```driver.find_elements_by_xpath```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

[image: object is not iterable]

...implies that you are trying to iterate through a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) where as only *list* objects are iterable.

---

### Solution

Within the `for()` loop to create a *list* to iterate through it's elements, instead of using `find_element*` you need to use **`find_elements*`**. So your effective code block will be:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path):
    i.click()
```