# TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable error while iterating through a ordered list in HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to write a script that gives me my homework for the day on Google Classroom, and there is a drop down menu that has all the different homework within the "ol" and "/ol" tags.
When I try to go through it and put the work in a dictionary with the name and class, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable
```

And I have no idea why, since I think a list is supposed to be iterable.

(There's the code):

```
def get_work(schoolUser, schoolPassword):

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("https://classroom.google.com/u/0/h")
    browser.maximize_window()
    

    emailLogin = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
    emailLogin.send_keys(schoolUser + Keys.ENTER)
    
    password =  WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")))
    passwordLogin.send_keys(schoolPassword + Keys.ENTER)
    browser.implicitly_wait(123)

    browser.find_element_by_class_name("R06fGe").click()  #Work To Do

    noDueDateList = browser.find_element_by_class_name("e2urcc")
    homework = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
    work = {}
    for homework in enumerate(noDueDateList):
        work["{0}".format(homework.text): "a"]
```

(Btw I have no idea how to work with dictionaries so that final part with the dictionary might be wrong, but I'll figure it out.)

And a way too simplified version of the HTML:

```
<div class>
    <ol class="classname" etc...>
        <li class = "classname1" insert bunch of attributes here>
        <li class = "classname2" insert bunch of attributes here>
        <li class = "classname1" insert bunch of attributes here>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the `emailLogin = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')` to `emailLogin = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')`

Answer (score 0):

It is not that clear in your question, what is the exact problem and how the html looks like, but if `e2urcc` is the class of your `ol` and you want all the `li` than you can go this way:

```
for homework in find_elements_by_css_selector('ol.e2urcc li'):
    print(homework.text)
```

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work, same error. But I'll put in the list HTML

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable
```

...implies that you are trying to iterate through a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) where as only *list* objects are iterable.

---

### Solution

Within the `for()` loop to create a *list* to iterate through it's elements, instead of using `find_element*` you need to use **`find_elements*`**. So your effective code block will be:

```
noDueDateList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("e2urcc")
homework = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
work = {}
for homework in enumerate(noDueDateList):
    work["{0}".format(homework.text): "a"]
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable error cycling through pages on a dynamic webpage with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460253/typeerror-firefoxwebelement-object-is-not-iterable-error-cycling-through-page/65460514#65460514)

Comment: I'm so sorry for not saying that in my question, but I already tried that and I got the same error.(Gonna edit it rn)